# How to push web notification by button click

Tags: php, jquery, web, notifications, service-worker

So I am practicing on web notification and I bumped into this tutorial https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/ I don't quite understand all of the code here but I am trying to do it by trying it one by one, but my one problem is how do I push web notification by button?

These are my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Push Codelab</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Push Codelab</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Welcome to the push messaging codelab. The button below needs to be
    fixed to support subscribing to push.</p>
    <p>
      <button disabled class="js-push-btn mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        Enable Push Messaging
      </button>

      <button  class="js-push-btn mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" id="notify">
        Enable Push Messaging
      </button>
    </p>
    <section class="subscription-details js-subscription-details is-invisible">
      <p>Once you've subscribed your user, you'd send their subscription to your
      server to store in a database so that when you want to send a message
      you can lookup the subscription and send a message to it.</p>
      <p>To simplify things for this code lab copy the following details
      into the <a href="https://web-push-codelab.glitch.me//">Push Companion
      Site</a> and it'll send a push message for you, using the application
      server keys on the site - so make sure they match.</p>
      <pre><code class="js-subscription-json"></code></pre>
    </section>
  </main>

  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BMpQ-7s56rTLKF7lR6wWQP9kKCbP3Q7Kidi96lHvREfmVV1mFtmSo08g_FuJ9vJkyGefboFo1Nj0JPlR2er9NLM';

const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');
const notifyButton = document.querySelector('#notify');

let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

    swRegistration = swReg;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}

function initializeUI() {
  // Set the initial subscription value
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);

    if (isSubscribed) {
      console.log('User IS subscribed.');
    } else {
      console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
    }

    updateBtn();
  });
}

function updateBtn() {
  if (isSubscribed) {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
  } else {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
  }

  pushButton.disabled = false;
}

navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
.then(function(swReg) {
  console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

  swRegistration = swReg;
  initializeUI();
})

function initializeUI() {
  pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    if (isSubscribed) {
      // TODO: Unsubscribe user
    } else {
      subscribeUser();
    }
  });

  // Set the initial subscription value
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    if (isSubscribed) {
      console.log('User IS subscribed.');
    } else {
      console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
    }

    updateBtn();
  });
}

function subscribeUser() {
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    isSubscribed = true;

    updateBtn();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    updateBtn();
  });
}

function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
  // TODO: Send subscription to application server

  const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
  const subscriptionDetails =
    document.querySelector('.js-subscription-details');

  if (subscription) {
    subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription);
    subscriptionDetails.classList.remove('is-invisible');
  } else {
    subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
  }
}

function updateBtn() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    return;
  }

  if (isSubscribed) {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
  } else {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
  }

  pushButton.disabled = false;
}

pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pushButton.disabled = true;
  if (isSubscribed) {
    unsubscribeUser();
  } else {
    subscribeUser();
  }
});

function unsubscribeUser() {
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    if (subscription) {
      return subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
  })
  .then(function() {
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);

    console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
    isSubscribed = false;

    updateBtn();
  });
}

function unsubscribeUser() {
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    if (subscription) {
      return subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
  })
  .then(function() {
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);

    console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
    isSubscribed = false;

    updateBtn();
  });
}

function pushNotification(){
    swRegistration.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
        console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

        const title = 'Push Codelab';
        const options = {
            body: 'Yay it works.',
            icon: 'images/icon.png',
            badge: 'images/badge.png'
        };

        event.waitUntil(swRegistration.registration.showNotification(title, options));
    });

    swRegistration.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

        event.notification.close();

        event.waitUntil(
            clients.openWindow('https://developers.google.com/web/')
        );
    });
}

notifyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("alert");
    pushNotification();
})
```

sw.js

```
'use strict';

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

    const title = 'Push Codelab';
    const options = {
        body: 'Yay it works.',
        icon: 'images/icon.png',
        badge: 'images/badge.png'
    };

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow('https://developers.google.com/web/')
    );
});
```

as you can see, I added a new function called **pushNotification();** that is used when notify button is clicked, but it wont send notification. Is there a simplier code to this? My brain is already falling apart.

Currently I can push notification by accessing my developers mode > application > service worker the push. But I want it by the button I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I already got the answer, showNotification is all I need, for anyone who have the same question, try this. Worked for me.

```
notifyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const title = 'Simple Title';
    const options = {
      body: 'Simple piece of body text.\nSecond line of body text :)'
    };
    swRegistration.showNotification(title, options);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this implementation should go to service worker js file, so that any push arriving are shown to user without manual intervention required by end user-
self.registration.**showNotification**(...)

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
        return;
    }
    var data = {};
    if (event.data) {
        data = event.data.json();
    }
    console.log('Notification Received:');
    console.log(data);
    try {
        var title = data.title;
        var message = data.message;
        var url = data.data.url;
        var icon = "images/ns-logo.png";

        event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: message,
            icon: icon,
            badge: icon,
            data: url
        }));
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Notification Processing Failed:', err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've already registered ***sw.js*** and allow ***permission*** of notification of browser.

**HTML**

```
<button id="ABCD" class="btn btn-block">Notify</button>
```

**Your JS**

```
var btnnotify = document.querySelector('#ABCD');
btnnotify.addEventListener('click', function () {
   navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(sw => {
       let options = {
           body: "Let's buy some Nendoroid!",
           icon: "img/Sukusuku Hakutaku.png",
        };
   sw.showNotification("I want to buy a Nendoroid!", options);
   });

});
```